# LINQ - An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: linq, ado.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

This is my first LINQ query and I have following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`Microsoft.LightSwitch.IDataServiceQueryable<LightSwitchApplication.LettersSentItem>`'
>   to '`System.Linq.IQueryable<LightSwitchApplication.LettersSentItem>`'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
partial void PatientReminders_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<LettersSentItem> query)
{
    query = from Ltr in PatientsLettersSentDetails
            where Ltr.ResponseTime > 28
            select Ltr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point out the line maybe ?

And this error is pretty trivial, its expecting a `Microsoft.LightSwitch.IDataServiceQueryable` and you are giving it a `IQueryable`. You need to either send an ÌDataServiceQueryable`or transform either one of the expressions to the other type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I still have error. Except this time there is no error on VS but when I hit f5 the screen is not displaying any results.

`partial void PatientReminders_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<LettersSentItem> query)
        {
            query = query.Where(l => DateTime.Compare(l.DateSent, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-28)) < 0 && (!l.ResponseReceived.HasValue || !l.ResponseReceived.Value));
        }`